# Java Spring: can a proxied object return another proxied object?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, remoting

I have a situation like this in Java:

```
interface IService {
    IMyObject getObject();
}

// This class is not serializable...
class NotSerializable implements IMyObject {
    ...
}
```

I've set up Spring 3.1 remoting so that my client gets a proxied reference to an IService implementation.  This implementation returns the non-serializable object when getObject() is called, which causes a marshaling exception.  **Is there a way to get Spring to automatically return a proxy for the IMyObject implementation?**  The client code would look like:

```
IService remoteService = ....;            // Get proxied service object from Spring.
IMyObject o = remoteService.getObject();  // Returns a proxied IMyObject
o.someMethod();                           // Runs the method on the proxied object.
```

Thanks!